# Yii 2.0 multiple text field validation

Tags: php, yii2

I want to apply validations in multiple fields in form ....text fields create dynamic,
like--

```
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($modelsForm->locale_models as $key => $value):
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <?= Html:: activeHiddenInput($value, "[$key]id"); ?>
            <?= Html:: activeHiddenInput($value, "[$key]brand_id"); ?>
            <?= Html:: activeHiddenInput($value, "[$key]model_id"); ?>
            <?= $form->field($value, "[$key]name")->textInput(); ?>
            <?= $form->field($value, "[$key]lang_code")->textInput(['readonly' => true]); ?>          
            <?= $form->field($value, "[$key]description")->textArea() ?>                
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you need create custom validation and please have look loadmulitple library in yii 2 

    <?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Site;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $settings = Setting::find()->One('id')->all();

        if (Model::loadMultiple($settings, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($settings)) {
          //check here  
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 has some built-in methods to achieve that.

I recommend reading [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html) from official docs.

Here is example from there:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Setting;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $settings = Setting::find()->indexBy('id')->all();

        if (Model::loadMultiple($settings, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($settings)) {
            foreach ($settings as $setting) {
                $setting->save(false);
            }
            return $this->redirect('index');
        }

        return $this->render('update', ['settings' => $settings]);
    }
}
```

Also see detailed docs for ActiveRerord methods [loadMultiple()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#loadMultiple%28%29-detail) and [validateMultiple()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#validateMultiple%28%29-detail).